# XNA WP7 - Open file without reading it all into memory?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I'd like to be able to open a file on Windows Phone 7, in an XNA game, without reading the entire file into memory.  I'm trying to stream audio from WAV files, to be passed to DynamicSoundEffectInstance for playback.

The method I have now uses TitleContainer.OpenStream() to open the WAV file, and then reads it on a background thread using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem().  However, this causes a hitch at the beginning, and today I verified that TitleContainer.OpenStream() returns a MS.Internal.InternalMemoryStream object, which would suggest that it's reading the entire file into memory in OpenStream().

This is corroborated by the fact that it seems to take effectively no time (or, only a memcpy()'s worth of time) to do the Read(), and that Stream.BeginRead() (which is included on WP7 as part of the Async CTP) calls its callback before returning.

Is there any way to open a file on WP7 XNA without reading the entire thing into memory?  If not, this is completely ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to do this.  However, since I know the size of the chunks I want to read (32kB), I can split the files into chunks offline and read them one chunk at a time.